# Get Type From null object

Tags: c#, reflection, types

First:

```
public class ClassePrincipal
{
    [Key] public long IdPrinc { get; set; }
    public string NomePrinc { get; set; }
    public string Princ { get; set; }


    public override string ToString()
    {
        return "ID: " + IdPrinc + " NomePrinc: " + NomePrinc + " Princ: " + Princ;
    }
}
```

Second:

```
public class Classe_Secundaria
{
    [Key] public long IdSec { get; set; }
    public string NomeSec { get; set; }
    public string Sec { get; set; }


    [Primary] public ClassePrincipal ClassePrincipal { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return "ID Sec: " + IdSec + " NomeSec: " + NomeSec + " Sec: " + Sec + (ClassePrincipal != null ? " ClassePrincipal: " + ClassePrincipal.ToString() : "");

    }
}
```

I use this:

```
Classe_Secundaria x = null;
```

I need get Type from x, but x is Null, how can I get Type from x using reflection? without reflection I used:

```
Type type = TypedReference.GetTargetType(__makeref(x));
```

When I use this code in reflection he got only Object Type, and not Classe_Secundaria type

Comment: why can't you use `typeof(Classe_Secundaria )`.*how can I get Type from x using reflection?* in this case you can't since you can't call `GetType()` and without `Type` reflection won't work

Comment: There is no way you can obtain the type of a `null` reference because it does not carry any type.

Comment: In your real code are you trying to get a type of a local variable or of an argument passed to a method?

Comment: Alex, I passed a object to a method, this case is null

Comment: What does the method look like? Can you show it?